# Why is Time.fixedTime and family a float and not a double?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Just want know if I'm missing something. I'm from ObjC land where NSTimeInterval is a double, which gives "sub-millisecond precision within a range of 10,000 years". Compare this to Unity, which since it uses a float for time, starts to break down after a day (maybe even sooner). Math.Approximately(1 day, a day + 1 frame) returns true for example (whereas 1 hour vs 1 hour + 1 frame correctly returns false). I actually experienced this when I left my game open all night and came back to it, noticing strange behavior on things that were time dependent.

Answer (score 3):

Unity internally uses a double to track time. The double is converted to a float before being passed to user code.

This is largely because Unity uses floats in most other locations (floats are much better supported on a range of graphics cards/platforms).

Since Unity uses a double internally, you don't need to worry about it losing count / failing to increment time.

What you do need to worry about is that after the game has been running for a number of hours, the representable values become more and more sparse.

This can cause things that moved smoothly to start stuttering.

Personally, I tend to keep my own (float) and reset it to zero at some sensible interval, ideally when it makes no difference (which depends what you're using it for).

Comment: Here http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/time-class-floating-point-accuracy.123344/ is the same answer by a Unity dev too, just to validate what you pointed.

Comment: @arielsan Good find. The last comment on that thread is actually mine

Answer (score 2):

If Unity uses float for time then Unity is making a huge mistake and you should use other sources for time. The 24-bit precision of a float means that after a day you will only have about 4 ms accuracy. Bugs may start showing up long before that, and some games actually need time to be stable for much longer than a day.

Even if it doesn't seem like you need much time precision, using float means that your time precision is dropping as the game goes on, adding an extra cause for bugs.

There are many games that have had bugs because they use floats for time, and burning that bad decision into a game engine is a terrible idea. I discussed this problem a few years ago after seeing this mistake repeated many times in the games I was working on at the time:

https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/13/dont-store-that-in-a-float/

The main recommendation is to use double or int64 for time, and if you use double then start it with a value of about 5 billion so that your precision will be consistent throughout your game, instead of gradually dropping.

Answer (score 1):

Unity3d uses floats for many components in the engine. Therefore you will find that a lot of functions and values will return floats or store floats respectively. Once you have been programming in Unity3d for a while you will even get the inside joke on their builds -- usually they look like this: 4.3.1f -- everything is a float.

You should be able to use .NET to get time in double if you use C#. Also I highly recommend, for some things, using the .NET Math class instead of the Unity `Math.h`, one is fast the other is in floats.

Answer (score 0):

Float is used not only in time representation but everywhere in Unity and in most engines simply because it's good enough for games and uses less resources. By "good enough" I mean that you probably won't need more precision in most situations. Like the example you gave, it's very rare that someone will run into this situation.

In [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4201/float-double-or-both-for-2d-vector-class) question, there's this very nice answer:

> Floats have no problem doing precise integer arithmetic up to 2<sup>24</sup>, which is what most people are (mostly irrationally) afraid of. Doubles do not solve the problem of common values being unrepresentable exactly - whether you get 0.10000001 or 0.10000000000000001, you still must make sure your code considers it "equal" to 0.09999999.
>
> Doubles are slower on every platform you'll care about writing games, take twice the memory bandwidth, and have fewer specialized CPU instructions available.
>
> Single-precision floats remain the standard for hardware graphics interfaces, both on the C/C++ side and inside shaders.

Comment: It's correct that in many situations 32-bit floats give enough precision, and asking for more is just wasteful. However, time is an interesting exception and [good arguments have been advanced](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/13/dont-store-that-in-a-float/) in favour of standardizing on doubles for this purpose. It was once a rare edge case to play/pause a game long enough for a float time-since-start value to lose needed precision. Now, many consoles are "always on" & suspend rather than close games, so a "single session" (in terms of game-time-since-startup) can easily span days